# Need to save which checkboxes will be shown as options

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have these checkboxes on a page and on another page I have these same checkboxes.

```
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">    
        <h2>Kies categorieen</h2>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input type="checkbox" name="categorie-kijk" id="goedkoop-bier-kijk" class="custom" />
                <label for="goedkoop-bier-kijk">Goedkoop bier</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categorie-kijk" id="muziek-kijk" class="custom" />
                <label for="muziek-kijk">Muziek</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categorie-kijk" id="gezelligheid-kijk" class="custom" />
                <label for="gezelligheid-kijk">Gezelligheid</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#bekijken2" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Toon</a></p> 

    </div>
```

Now I want to save the checked values of the page below to influence the values of the page above. When the user clicks the button 'Opslaan' below, it should save which checkboxes are checked and only show those in the page above.
So, for example, if only the checkbox with id "gezelligheid-fav" was checked and saved, the page above should only show the checkbox "gezelligheid-kijk".

```
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">    
        <h2>Selecteer favorieten</h2>   
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input type="checkbox" name="categorie-fav" id="goedkoop-bier-fav" class="custom" />
                <label for="goedkoop-bier-fav">Goedkoop bier</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categorie-fav" id="muziek-fav" class="custom" />
                <label for="muziek-fav">Muziek</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categorie-fav" id="gezelligheid-fav" class="custom" />
                <label for="gezelligheid-fav">Gezelligheid</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#instellingen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back">Opslaan</a></p>   
    </div>
```

Does anyone know how I should do this?

Comment: are you posting the form to another page when you are saving the checkboxes

Comment: it's a multipage application, just like this one: jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html
so, it should somehow be saved when I press the button "Opslaan", and it should make it visible on another 'page', but it's all in the same HTML document.

Comment: If the design is same you don't need two pages. Post the form in the same page but saving all the ids of checked boxes in a hidden variable. Then receive the hidden variable after posting. That's the concept. But you need to implement it in mobile version (i guess)

Comment: since its a checkbox wat if user selects two checboxes an saves (click OPSlaan button)...

Comment: @bipen: Then it should show two checkboxes in the '-kijk' page (the code in the upper block). And when three are selected, it should show three.

Comment: @polin: If that works, it would be great, but how do I do it?

Comment: can u create a JSfiddle of this??  So that till willbe easy for us to check the answer...

Comment: I have adapted the JSfiddle that dencey made, so it's shown with jquey mobile layout, but now it doesn't even want to get any checkboxes checked. http://jsfiddle.net/CdyS8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assueming that two groups have same number of checkboxs and in the same order,
using jQuery, bind the click event on the 'Opslaan' button with this handler:

```
function() {
    var cbxs1 = $('input[name="categorie-fav"]'),
        cbxs2 = $('input[name="categorie-kijk"]');
    cbxs1.each(function(index) {
        cbxs2[index].checked = this.checked;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm probably doing something wrong, cause it ain't working yet. I put it in this script:
     $('#favOpslaan').click(function(){
        var cbxs1 = $('input[name="categorie-fav"]'),
        cbxs2 = $('input[name="categorie-kijk"]');
        cbxs1.each(function(index) {
        cbxs2[index].checked = this.checked;
       });
and I bound it to the button like this:
    <a href="#instellingen" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" id="favOpslaan">Opslaan</a>

Comment: It's correct about your script, i also don't know why it dosen't work, need more info, you can check this demo [http://jsfiddle.net/CdyS8/](http://jsfiddle.net/CdyS8/)

Comment: will it matter where I put this script?

Comment: Also, instead of checking the corresponding checkboxes, I would like to only show the checkboxes in the -kijk section if they are checked in the -fav section. Is that possible?